# Finding the position of an item in Hash Table

Tags: c++, arrays, hash, hashtable

As you have known, the Hashing table is a type of Data structure. As learning about this data structure, I find it hard to understand the algorithms of finding the position of a given item. I call it **findPos** and its source code as following:

```
int findPos(const HashedObject &x) const
{
    int offset = 1;
    int CurrentPos = hashfunction(x);
    while(array[CurrentPos].info != Inactive && array[CurrentPos].element != x)
    {
        CurrentPos += offset;
        offset += 2;
        if(CurrentPos >= array.size())
        {
            CurrentPos -= array.size();
        }
    }
    return CurrentPos;
}
```

I will explain some function which has been used in this source code.

- `hashfunction(int x)`: This function is used to find the initial position for a key `x`. If you have known hashtable, you will understand it.
- `array` here is the table that I have made to find the position. The object `array` has 2 main properties: info and element. `array.element` contains the data of each element in the array. `array.info` contains the status of the element of the array: Active (Available), Deleted, and Inactive(free) (I used `enum` for these status)

The problem here is the `offset`. As far as I know, when I want to find a position of a given element I need to scan through the table according to the value of `x`. But I don't know why they use `offset` here instead of reusing the hash function again to find the next position. Moreover, I find that offset is incremented by 2 after a loop which made me really confused.

Comment: This called [quadratic probing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_probing)

Comment: If they reused the hash function, they'd just find the same position again. Quadriatic probing is a form of *open addressing*, where other entries in the table are examined if the element isn't found in the expected location.

Comment: @john no, actually my hashfunction is only linear probing

Comment: Hash functions should not do any form of collision detection, so you are mistaken.

Comment: As you said yourself `This function is used to find the initial position`

Comment: Suppose the hash function returns `1000` and suppose that the searched for item isn't found. Then as you go around the while loop `CurrentPos` will have the following values, `1000`, `1001`, `1004`, `1009`, `1016`, `1025` etc. This is why it's called quadratic probing because the positions searched increase as the square of the number of iterations performed.

Comment: @john I see that but actually, the my hashfunction is only linear, not quadratic probing

Comment: @john One more thing is that is it a good way to set ``offset += 2`` instead of ``offset += 1``? I think ``2`` may lead to the wrong searching in the table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213989/discussion-between-john-and-hoang-nam).

Comment: `offset += 2` is correct for quadratic probing, for linear probing you would just say `CurrentPos += 1` and not have the `offset` variable at all. And finally there's no such thing as a linear hash function, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @john I think that I have misunderstood here. Anyway I think it's ok now. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

So let me explain you the above code, firstly in the code they have passed value x in the "*currentpos*" and one more thing "*currentpos*" is indexes that we are passing in the *.And as you asked that why they have used offset so they have used "*offset*" to increase the "*current position* *i.e offset is the value by which the currentpos will be increased* ".

If above statement confuses you then for time being just assume that they have used "*offset* " as a *iterator* like we used *" i "* in loops.

They have used [*Linear Probing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probing) in this code and every time the value of the offset is increased by 2.

==>  **Why " 2 "?**

As i said the have used linear probing but in linear probing the value of offset is increased by 2 in this case not by 1 according the writer of the code so you have check it with the writer or from wherever you got this code from.

Still if you face any problem just feel free to ask .

Comment: This is quadratic probing rather than linear probing, as the offset is increasing on each iteration.